# MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION column now only available on API 29?

Tags: android, mediastore

For some reason the MediaStore column `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION` is now only available on API29 and Android Studio now shows a warning that it requires Android Q.

I'm not sure why because i have been using this column for a long time.

Even in the docs it says **Added in API29**.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DURATION

Comment: Well this post says, it is a error in documentation. It was definitely not added in Android Q, It is available in below OS as well, I have used it. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ehlu7b/mediastoreaudiomediaduration_exists_on_android_pie/

Comment: I have noticed the same for MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN. The documentation says that it is only available from Android Q. I've posted a question to ask if it really the case. Please help to answer if you happen to know thank you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376737/is-mediastore-mediacolumnsdate-taken-only-available-from-api-level-29