# Is MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATE_TAKEN only available from API level 29?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, mediastore, android-10.0

I am trying to use [MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATE_TAKEN) and getting warning from Android Studio IDE that it requires API 29 (Android Q). The official Google documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATE_TAKEN) says this was Added in API level 29. Is this really true?

I've checked the Google Sources from past releases all the way back until API 19 (KitKat) and I saw MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATE_TAKEN field being available since then. Why is the official documentation saying something different?

Android 4.4 (KitKat) [MediaStore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java)

Android 5.0 (Lollipop) [MediaStore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/lollipop-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java)

Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) [MediaStore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java)

Android 7.0 (Nougat) [MediaStore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/nougat-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java)

Android 8.0 (Oreo) [MediaStore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java)

Android 9.0 (Pie) [MediaStore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/pie-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java)

Can someone please clarify the truth? Can I reliably use [MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATE_TAKEN) from API 19+? Thanks!

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing, and I'm quite bummed no one has replied yet.

Comment: I've decided to take the risk and use it for API 19 devices as well. For the mean time, I've created a documentation issue ticket for Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174826992

Comment: I'm found the same issue and can say that we use DATE_TAKEN field even before API 19. I can found it even in Donut version.
But actually not all apps setup this field correctly, may be MediaStore use exif info for this, but for many third party Camera apps this field is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57762138/9150068).

From the [Api diff for level 29](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/29-incr/changes), we can see that `DATE_TAKEN` has always been there, even if the api level is below 29. The only difference is that before Android Q this const was in `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns` but was moved to `MediaStore.MediaColumns` by now. Meanwhile `ImageColumns` extends `MediaColumns`. **So the lint cannot identify them accurately.**

**However, the value itself does not change before and after the move.** So you can just ignore the warning.